# Will a 3GB/s SAS RAID Controller (Dell PERC 6/i) support 12GB/s SAS HDDs?

Tags: dell, dell-perc, perc6, seagate

will a **3GB/s SAS RAID Controller** (Dell PERC 6/i) support **12GB/s SAS HDDs** (Seagate ST2000NM0034)?

And: Will this RAID Controller support the full size (2 TB) of the HDDs?

Greetz from Austria, Florian Miesenberger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disks will be backwards compatible with earlier generation SAS. So the speed would just downshift to 3Gbps.

However, since your server and PERC controller are old, it may make sense to find some period-correct SAS disks.

Either way, the 2TB disk capacity is also supported. That is the maximum for the controller.